# how do i add last name new field in default user registration page

Tags: theming

how do i add last name new field in default user registration form my code is

```
$form['account']['lname'] = array('#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('LastName'),
  '#default_value' => $edit['LastName'],
  '#maxlength' => LASTNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
  '#description' => t('Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, and underscores.'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

but i don't know how to show last name field in default user registration form?

Comment: Do you use Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: me using drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [content profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module, you can add new fields to a users profile just like how you use cck to add new fields to a node. There is a configuration option where you can then set which fields you want displayed on the registration form.

Comment: me getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the form by implementing hook_form_alter.

Alternatively you can have a look at the content profile and cck module to get additional user fields without coding.

Comment: me getting this error

user warning: Duplicate entry '' for key 'name' query: INSERT INTO users (timezone, pass, init, status, created) VALUES (18000, 'b6708e13de1fd0c2d230b1d0bf6c1c03', '', 1, 1326450740) in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\user\user.module on line 328. Error saving user account

Comment: This means that you try to insert a user name into the db which already exists. The users table requires the name to be unique.

Comment: then how can resolve this issue or error?

Comment: Make sure you do not test registration two times with the same user name. The above query doesn't even set a user name. This will always fail, since the name field cannot be null.

Comment: then what can i do now ?